# Cache locking with static object in generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, caching

I have a generic base class for value caching functionality.

```
public abstract class CachedValueProviderBase<T> : ICachedValueProvider<T> where T : class
{
    private Cache Cache { set; get; }
    protected string CacheKey { get; set; }
    protected int CacheSpanInMinutes { get; set; }

    private static readonly object _cacheLock = new object();

    public T Values
    {
        get
        {
            T value = Cache[CacheKey] as T;
            if (value == null)
            {
                lock (_cacheLock)
                {
                    value = Cache[CacheKey] as T;
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        value = InitializeCache();
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
    }

    protected CachedValueProviderBase()
    {
        Cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
        CacheSpanInMinutes = 15;
    }

    public T CacheValue(T value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            lock (_cacheLock)
            {
                Cache.Insert(CacheKey, value, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(CacheSpanInMinutes),
                             Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    private T InitializeCache()
    {
        T value = Initialize();
        CacheValue(value);

        return value;
    }

    protected abstract T Initialize();
}
```

I have several classes that make use of this base class and as long as the T is different it is fine. When two sub classes use the same T, string for example, they share the same cache lock object. What is the best way of implementing the logic in a base class but still giving each sub class it's own cache lock object?

**Update**
After the suggestions below I have updated my class:

```
public abstract class CachedValueProviderBase<T> : ICachedValueProvider<T> where T : class
    {
        private Cache Cache { set; get; }
        protected string CacheKey { get; set; }
        protected int CacheSpanInMinutes { get; set; }
        private object _cacheLock = new object();

        public T Values
        {
            get
            {
                T value = Cache[CacheKey] as T;
                if (value == null)
                {
                    lock (_cacheLock)
                    {
                        value = Cache[CacheKey] as T;
                        if (value == null)
                        {
                            value = InitializeCache();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return value;
            }
        }

        protected CachedValueProviderBase()
        {
            Cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
            CacheSpanInMinutes = 15;
        }

        public T CacheValue(T value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                Cache.Insert(CacheKey, value, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(CacheSpanInMinutes),
                             Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

            }

            return value;
        }

        private T InitializeCache()
        {
            T value = Initialize();
            CacheValue(value);

            return value;
        }

        protected abstract T Initialize();
    }
}
```

My sub classes are now singletons so I could get rid of the static cachelock object making it an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just remove the static modifier on your cacheLock object.

That keyword forces the field to be shared between all instances of subclasses that share the same generic parameter type.

If you remove it, the cacheLock object will be private to **each instance** of a subclass, regardless of the generic parameter's type.

```
 private static readonly object _cacheLock = new object();
```

Should be :

```
 private readonly object _cacheLock = new object();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is running on a webserver so I still have to lock the cache for multiple threads. When removing static there could be more than one thread initializing the cache.

Comment: Then you should consider using the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your cache providers, so that you have a single cache regardless of the thread accessing it, while keeping a unique cache lock for each cache instance.

Comment: @b3n If you are using .net 4.0 you can use `Lazy<T>` for thread-safe ininitalization. Anyway, static locks for instance methods are **bad** thing.

Comment: If I follow the singleton path, how can I keep my code above in a base class? I would have to pull down the cache lock to the sub class so the base class would break where it tries to lock.

Comment: No. The singleton pattern has nothing to do with that, it's used to guarantee that you have a unique instance of an object throughout the application. You however need to use a thread-safe implementation of the singleton pattern. It will not break your cache provider implementation.

Comment: Yep I should have said I don't need the cache lock to be static anymore because there will only ever be one instance of my class.

Answer (score 1):

I had to take a good look at your code, to find out if it was correct. Once I noticed your cache is a `HttpRuntime.Cache`, it made sense. The `HttpRuntime.Cache` is thread-safe. Otherwise you would have had several thread-safety problems. With your current, code I advice you to do the following:

```
private string CacheKey { get; set; }

protected CachedValueProviderBase(string cacheKey)
{
    this.CacheKey = cacheKey + "_" + typeof(T).FullName;
}
```

By supplying the `cacheKey` as constructor argument and making the property private (or readonly would do), you prevent it from being changed by later on. By appending the type name to the key, you prevent cache conflicts since everybody is using the same cache.

One last note. The `lock` in the `CacheValue` method is redundant, since the `Cache` is thread-safe.

Comment: So I can basically get rid of the cache lock object seeing that Cache is threadsafe?

Comment: It depends. When looking at your code I got the idea that `Values` gets called from multiple threads and that you wanted to prevent `InitializeCache` from being called multiple times. If that's that case, the lock is in place. If you don't care for the value to be created multiple times (and one gets thrown away), in that case the lock is redundant.

Comment: Steven, I supply the cache key in my sub classes and I make sure they don't use the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by implementing an abstract method in my base class GetCacheLockObject().

```
protected abstract object GetCacheLockObject();
```

Each derived class then returns its own reference to the cache lock object:

```
private static readonly object _cacheLockObject = new Object();

protected override object GetCacheLockObject()
{
    return _cacheLockObject;
}
```

Calls to lock in the shared base class caching code then reference this method rather than an object in the base class.